# How to use the offset method with named ranges

Tags: vba, excel

There maybe better logic to this, but using the note to the user is the only way I understand making this selection work. Maybe you have something better.

I'm pretty much a newbie running Excel 2010 on an Windows XP machine.

I have a named range (say A2:D8) that I call GanttArea. In A8 is a note to the user saying "Any additional lines must be inserted above this line." This is because I don't know how else to make sure the user adds their additional lines in the right place, and I don't know if they will add other lines a few cells later under here that don't apply to what I'm trying to capture.

If I enter

```
Sub SelectRange()
    Range("GanttArea").select
End Sub
```

It will select the named range. I want it to move up one row so not to include my note. 
If I enter

```
Sub SelectRange()
    Range("GanttArea").Offset(-1,0).Select
End Sub
```

It does move the row up for the selection like I want but now it includes the row A1:D1 which are the heading rows. I'm trying to select the data dynamically for a gantt chart so this won't work.

It just occurred to me that maybe the offset is not changing the selection but just moving the same number of selected cells up one row.

How can I make the named range expand or contract so the user can add or delete rows?

Thank you,
Kirk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Resize` method instead of `Offset`, so:

```
Sub SelectRange()
    Dim rng as Range: Set rng = Range("GanttArea")

    Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count)
    rng.Select

End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could simply define your named range using the `Offset` function.

These are a little tricky to set up, but as long as your column A does not contain any blank cells, this should work.  In your names manager, enter this formula for the GantArea:

`=OFFSET($A$1,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1,4)`

If you do this, you should be able to insert additional rows anywhere in the table area and as long as those rows are not empty values in column A, the range will resize dynamically based on that formula.

[image]

Comment: +1 for using a named range with a computed size. Had not seen that trick before - love it! I take it that updates automatically every time the name is referenced?

Comment: @Floris not sure if it would update when the name is *referenced* (e.g., as an argument in another formula), but then again I'm not sure if it needs to, since, as a general formula won't alter the dimensions of this range anyways. But yes, dynamically named ranges are pretty fun to work with. They are great for charting dynamic/changing datasets, etc.

Comment: Thank you, David, The 2nd example, with the Offset in the Names Manager area seems to do the job. I’ll have to read up somewhere about this. It would have never occurred to me to add a VBA command there. I didn't even know you could put VBA outside of the macro. I did have some problems with the first example though. When I type it in (or copy and paste) the “Set Rng…” Shows up as red in my code. I was pretty sure I mistyped it but I’ve also copied it and it’s still not working. It seems to be a syntax error that I can’t find. When I run, it just says “Syntax Error.”

Comment: In the second option, it's not a VBA method, there it's a worksheet function called `Offset`.  For the first option, there is a typo, try this instead: `Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count)`

Comment: No problem. If it's solved your problem, do consider "Accepting" the answer so that others with similar questions can benefit from this explanation, too. Cheers!

Comment: 'Dynamic Named Ranges' are great, but be careful. Eg. If someone types something into A11 (Like 'TOTAL') the named range extend to include the blank row 8. Check out Excel TABLES (INSERT-->TABLE), which will create a named range as a byproduct and give the user a little more visual clues about whats happening.  Of course, these have their own trade offs too.  I wish Microsoft would just port the VBA 'CurrentRegion' property to an Excel function.

Comment: +1 @TimSands that goes along with my earlier comment about empty cell values, since I use the `CountA` in this function, any value in column A which is **not** part of the "table" data is going to cause unexpected results.

Comment: David I don't see where I Accept the answer. Please advise.

Comment: @user2498217 there should be a check mark at the top left of my answer near the up/down arrows and a number indicating how many votes the answer has received (currently, 4 but that could change) its grey but if you click it, it will turn green. That's all it takes.